# How change charset in Apache Commons Email?

Tags: java, email, apache-commons-email

I'm using Apache Commons email to send email to my clients, but I have a client called 'Semana da Computação' (in portugues BR) but it goes 'Semana da ComputaÃ§Ã£o' .
I try to modify my code, but it nothing working:

```
public static boolean emailWithImage(String subject, String message, String emailReceiver, String imageURL) {
    HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    email.setCharset("UTF-8"); // I change here, but it is not working
    email.setHostName(Constantes.EMAIL_HOST_NAME);
    email.setSmtpPort(587);
    DefaultAuthenticator authenticator =
            new DefaultAuthenticator(Constantes.EMAIL_USER, Constantes.EMAIL_PASSWORD);
    email.setAuthenticator(authenticator);
    email.setTLS(true);

    try {
        email.setFrom(Constantes.EMAIL_USER, Constantes.EMAIL_NAME);
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.addTo(emailReceiver);

        URL url = new URL(imageURL);
        String cid = email.embed(url, "image");        /* it must be 'cid' the name of the image */

        email.setHtmlMsg("<html><img src=\"cid:" + cid + "\"> <p>" + message + "</p> </html>"); /* set the html message */
        email.setTextMsg(message);                     /* send a alternative text in case when the email reader don't support html */

        email.send();
    } catch (EmailException ex) {
        return false;
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Any ideas? Why is the name not coming through correctly and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 27):

This also works,

```
email.setCharset("utf-8");
```

Alternatively if you are using 1.3,

```
email.setCharset(org.apache.commons.mail.EmailConstants.UTF_8);
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399187/apache-commons-email-and-utf-8

Comment: Still valid in 2021/08!

Answer (score 3):

It might work if instead of doing setHtmlMessage(...), you do

```
email.addPart("<html>body here</html>", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

Another alternative is to try and put the charset in the html,

```
email.setHtmlMsg("<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"></head>body here</html>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, and to resolve it, I have set the encoding to ISO-8859-1 and now it is working.

Comment: Hello user, you might show a code example to make this a more complete answer. Good luck, and hope this helps!